# jQuery find first cell of table td

Tags: jquery

i writing simple contexMenu for datatable.i'm using `datatables` class for create list of data. i want to find first cell of table on right click on each that, how can i find that?

sorry for my english
jquery:

```
    $("#showTopics tbody").bind("contextmenu",function(event) {
        var aata = $(this).children('tr').children('td').eq(0).text();
        alert(aata);
    return false;
});
```

HTML

```
<table id='showTopics' style='line-height:18px;'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style='width:30%;text-align:right;'>X"</th>
            <th style='width:7%;'>a</th>
            <th style='width:12%;'>b</th>
            <th style='width:11%;'>c</th>
            <th style='width:9%;'>d</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FaRSa/
However in your example you only put the event on `$("#showTopics tbody").`
And your HTML only shows content in the `thead`

In the fiddle I threw in another tr in the tbody and the function worked fine. :)

Comment: yes that work when i create tr handly and i'm using datatables class for create data

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#showTopics tr").bind("contextmenu",function(event) {
    var aata = $(this).children().siblings(':first').text();
    alert(aata);
    return false;
});
```